# Destroy a has_many :through is not working with link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a simple project management tool in Rails 4, and the part which gives me headaches has three main models: `Projects`, `Users` and `Memberships`.

Users can have many projects and projects can have many users.  I implemented a `has_many through` membership relationship between Projects and Users in the following manner:

Project:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :projects, through: :memberships
end
```

Membership:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project
end
```

So far I haven’t seen it on Stack Overflow, but I created a seperate controller for the Memberships, with a `:create` and `:destroy` only.
So far, `:create` seems to work just fine.

The main problem lies in the destroy function of the Memberships.
The destroy function I implemented is:

```
def destroy
    Membership.find(:id).destroy
    redirect_to current_project || request.referer
end
```

`rake routes` says that the membership path exists, but the following tries give me:

I tried to use a `link_to helper` to delete the memberships:

```
<%= link_to "delete", membership, method: :delete %> 
EDIT: error: undefined local variable or method `membership' 

<%= link_to "delete", @membership, method: :delete %>
EDIT: error: Sorry something went wrong --> goes to /memberships

<%= link_to "delete, membership_path(@membership), method: :delete %>
EDIT: error No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"memberships", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

which all give errors.

EDIT: on request also the `projects_controller #show` function

```
def show
    @user = current_user
    @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
    @members = @project.users
    @projects = @user.projects
    @membership = @project.memberships.build if logged_in?
    @memberships = @project.memberships
end
```

How can I make sure a membership is removed with the associated id in `@project.membership_ids`?  Should I include certain extra parameters?

Comment: What kind of errors do they give? Do the errors happen when you generate the link or when you click it?

Comment: Can you post the code for the controller action that displays the "delete" link to a membership? I think the problem lies in rendering that view, not the `destroy` method on the `MembershipController` class.

Comment: I added the Project#show function. So far the errors are raised when I click on the link, depending on the code for the membership path.

Answer (score 0):

`resources :memberships, only: [:create, :destroy]`

### Update

Don't know how I missed this earlier, in your destroy action you have `Membership.find(:id).destroy`. It should utilize params and be more along the lines of this:

```
# MembershipsController
def destroy
    @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
    if @membership.destroy
        redirect_to current_project || request.referer
    else
        #
    end
end
```

Your `ProjectsController`'s Show action isn't defining `@membership` as a `Membership` object.

```
def show
    @user = current_user
    @project = @user.projects.find(params[:id])
    @membership = Membership.find_by user: @user, project: @project

    # build is used for nested attributes, not sure why you'd have this in a show action...
    # @project.memberships.build if logged_in?

    # the following are redundant.
    @projects = @user.projects
    @members = @project.users
    @memberships = @project.memberships
end
```

In the view: `<%= link_to "delete", @membership, method: :delete %>`

If you want all memberships of a project or user to be destroyed upon parent deletion, make the following changes to your `User` & `Project` models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :memberships
end
```

Comment: The errors are included above. The routing is exactly the way you proposed. :)

Comment: It renders well, but when clicking on it, it routes to /memberships. There is no index, so it gives a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error.

Comment: Thank you @kjmagic13. It is still giving the "Couldn't find Project without an ID" error. But this could be because in the router file I have not nested memberships into projects but treat them as a seperate resource.. could this be a problem?

Comment: I found and fixed my problem, mostly because of your answer! So thank you :)
The problem was that I had to pass parameters in the delete request, otherwise it just didn't recognize where it had to go after the delete. I implemented a form_for with a method: :delete.

Answer (score -1):

The reason the your code did not work is because you did not specify the path to `link_to`. I do not believe you need to have `@membership` so I edited that out.

```
<%= link_to "delete", membership_path(@membership), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: Don't simply throw out code, instead *explain* why this should be used. Throwing code is like handing someone a fish. Explaining it is teaching them how to fish.

Comment: Fair enough. The reason the your code did not work is because you did not specify the path to link_to. I do not beleive you need to have @membership so I edited that out.

Comment: `membership_path` needs an object passed to it, otherwise Rails won't know what to delete.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify for you. The correct syntax is `membership_path(@membership)`. It's not another parameter in the `link_to` method.

Comment: you're right... it's early morning for me now that one slipped through the cracks!

Comment: This also gives errors.. I've included the errors above